# How can I load an image from a specific directory in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to load an image from a directory "../MyAppFolder/Logos".

**My code:**

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"/Logos/bitmap.bmp");
 pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

This code doesn't work. When I use (@"/Bitmapx.bmp") it works, but when I want to load an image from a deeper directory I get an error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what is the question? Plus your forward slashes should possibly be backslashes.

Comment: Than do so ;-) Honestly, what's your problem?

Comment: What is your question? You do not ask anything here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loading pictures from a folder on loading time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485969/loading-pictures-from-a-folder-on-loading-time)

Comment: What error message do you get? What is the actual full path string you are using?

Comment: @Elfoc you still need to define "doesn't work" better.  What error message do you get? Is it an exception or compile error? What exact folders have you tried, and for each attempt did it "succeed" or "fail"?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid when I use: 
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"\\Logos\\bitmapa.bmp"); When i use Habjan method: Error: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. My logos folder is in app root folder.

Comment: Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"Logos\\logo.bmp"); is working ! :) Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The leading slash targets the current drive root.  Use the realative path...

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"Logos/bitmap.bmp");
```

..Or one of the many `Path.` methods to resolve the full path that you want.

*and yes I know my example above targets the current working path... that would be why I added the above comment.  And for the pointless downvoter you might like to learn that current versions of Windows don't care which slash you use.*

Comment: Well it was what he asked... though he probably wanted ./Logos/bitmap.bmp (and the direction of the slash doesn't matter)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string myLogo = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Logos\bitmap.bmp");
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(myLogo);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

And make sure your Logos folder is in your application root folder.

Comment: Error: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. My logos folder is in app root folder.

Comment: @Elfoc: How about telling us what myLogo contains after the first line is run?

Comment: Make sure you have 1 \ in string part (@"Logos\bitmap.bmp") or if you have 2 then remove @.

Answer (score 3):

The first character of your path is `/` which makes this path relative to the root level of the drive on which the current working directory lives.  But you probably want a relative path so just remove the initial `/`.

What's more, relative paths are relative to the working directory. But the working directory is not necessarily the application directory. For example, if you navigate in a file dialog that can change your working directory.

If I were you I would probably pre-pend the path with the app directory and make it a fully-specified absolute path, exactly as HABJAN suggests.

Comment: Struggling to understand the downvote. Perhaps it's from someone who doesn't know that `/` is a perfectly reasonable path separator on Windows.

Comment: @Matthew it's always a risky business offering an answer on a .net question

Comment: That would be my guess... shame that some people aren't as smart as they think they are.